# Customized naming of columns in JPA relationships

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, entity-relationship

When I make relationsships with JPA using hibernate, some terrible long and ackward column names are generated.
Eg. I have the following `actionPlan_actionPlanPK`, which means that the column `actionPlan` is a FK that points to `actionPlanPK`.
To make it look just a little bit more neat in the DB I would like if I could give it a name myself, preferably just the name it has in the entity class that owns the relationship.

Is this possible with JPA?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. It is possible to specify your own name for a column if you are not satisfied with the default names. For instance in the class with the reference to the ActionPlan you can specify:

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="actionplanId")
public ActionPlan getActionPlan(){

}
```

And thus, the column name will be "actionplanid".

Comment: Just make sure to put it on the Many-side. If not I found out it did not work ;-)

Answer (score 3):

This capability is part of the JPA specification and allows for the naming of many of your database structures in the annotations.  These include:

Naming your table as follows:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="better_table_name")
public class MyConvolutedClassName {
}
```

Naming your columns as follows:

```
@Column(name="better_column_name")
private Date myConvolutedDateColumn;
```

Naming your columns that are part of a relationship:

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="better_join_column_name")
private ClassName otherModelClass;
```

There's a great (though not quite up-to-date) cheatsheet for EJB 3.0 annotations (which includes JPA) available at http://www.fnogol.de/media/ejb3.0-anno-cheat-1.2.pdf.